# What is the meaning of P.S. in a name?

Tags: names, suffixes

I have a project to parse names and there's a thing called *title* (mr. dr.), *suffix* (esq. ph.d.) and *generation* (ii, iii, jr.), but I don't have the faintest idea what "p.s." is.

It's in the following format and it's a lawyer:

> Sunde, Kit T. P.S.

Comment: Does this name appear in a long list of names, or in a letter, or something else? I guess I'm asking if the Letters could be unrelated to the name somehow.

Comment: It's definitely part of the name. It appears as I typed it above in a field specifically put there to indicate name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

P.S. Stands for *Professional Service Corporation* it's a legal designation like Inc. or LLC.

Answer (score 5):

Capitalised initials following a name often represent a **professional qualification**, falling within your suffix category.  For instance, a name listed as *John Smith, MD* tells you that John Smith is a doctor of medicine (MD is originally from the Latin “Medicinæ Doctor”).

So, that’s what I would expect them to be here.  There’s no qualification abbreviated as *P.S.* that’s well-known as *MD* or *PhD*, but googling suggests it can sometimes represent either *Professional Surveyor* or *Police Sergeant*.  For a lawyer, I guess *Professional Surveyor* is more likely.

Alternatively, the way you write it, `Sunde, Kit T. P.S.`, it looks perhaps like those are middle initials — some very prolix parents named him “Kit Thomas Percival Snyder Sunde” — and the space separating the `T.` and the `P.S.` comes just from careless typing.  Could that be the case in your source data?

Comment: Excellent point about it being middle initials. I think for my data set it isn't, but it's a good warning for others.

Answer (score 1):

Professional Surveyor. sometimes you will see it as P.S. and sometimes as PS.

I am a Professional Surveyor. some lawyers are surveyors also.

Answer (score 0):

It can be several things, depending on the person's profession, e.g. professional service, personal service, public servant…